# Remove "almost" duplicate rows (may or may not start with plus sign)

Tags: oracle-12c, duplication

To remove duplicated rows from Oracle, I tend to use the following:

```
DELETE FROM your_table
WHERE rowid not in
(SELECT MIN(rowid)
FROM your_table
GROUP BY column1, column2, column3);
```

(taken from [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/529119/2657875))

However, I'd like to remove the same rows in a slightly different scenario. Image there is a table with rows: `name`, `surname`. Duplicate row is when

1. `name` is the same, and
2. `surname` is the same, or starts with `+` (plus sign) and then is the same.

For example, the following is to be considered the same:

> name: John, surname Doe
>
> name: John, surname +Doe

How do I remove those duplicated rows?

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH cte AS(
SELECT rowid, name, 
CASE WHEN surname NOT LIKE '+%'
THEN '+' + surname
ELSE surname
END AS surname
FROM your_table)

DELETE FROM your_table
WHERE rowid NOT IN
(SELECT MIN(rowid)
 FROM cte
 GROUP BY name, surname
)
```